# Java HashMap containsKey strange behavior

Tags: java, hashmap, equals

Trying to realize simple task stuck into strange problem:

```
class User{
    String login;
    String pwrd;
    User(String lg,String pw){
        this.login=lg;
        this.pwrd=pw;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return this.login;
    }
    public boolean equals(String a){
        return this.login.equals(a);
    }
    public boolean equals(User t){
        return this.login.equals(t.toString());
    }
}

public class Foo{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        HashMap<User,Boolean> a=new HashMap<>();
        User a1=new User("asd","123"),a2=new User("asd","134");
        a.put(a1,false);
        a.put(a2,false);
        System.out.println(a.containsKey(a2));
        System.out.println(a.containsKey("asd"));
    }
}
```

As a result I expected both `containsKey` checks to be true. Further in code it would be used more and more. So the first thing is to understand why it behaves so and if possible fix it. Any help appreciated.

Comment: You should always add `@Override` when you *think* you are overriding a method, so the compiler can complain when you actually aren't (e.g. your `equals` methods here).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The keys of your Map are `User` instances, so `a.containsKey("asd")` will never return `true`, since "asd" is a String.

BTW, you didn't override `Object`'s `equals`, which expects an `Object` argument. This means that `a.containsKey(a2)` also returns `false`, since `a1==a2` is false.

A correct implementation of `equals` would be :

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other){
    if (!(other instanceof User))
        return false;
    User u = (User) other;
    return this.login.equals(u.login);
}
```

As Andy mentioned, you must also override `hashCode`, so that if `a.equals(b)` is true then `a.hashCode()==b.hashCode()`.

EDIT :

I think you can make `a.containsKey("asd")` return true if you override `equals` in a way that treats `String` instances as equal to your `User` instance if they match the `login` property :

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other){
    if (other instanceof User) {
        User u = (User) other;
        return this.login.equals(u.login);
    } else if (other instanceof String) {
        String u = (String) other;
        return this.login.equals(u);
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode()
{
    return login.hashCode();
}
```

I never tried such an implementation of `equals`, but based on my understanding of `HashMap`, it might work.

However, such an implementation of `equals` would violate the contract of `equals` as defined in the Javadoc of `Object`, since `"asd".equals(a1)` will return false even though `a1.equals("asd")` is true.

EDIT:

After checking the implementation of `HashMap`, I found this implementation of `equals` won't work, since the code of `containsKey(key)` compares the key against the keys of the existing entries instead of the other way round, and `String.equals(obj)` will always return false if `obj` is not a `String`. I guess there's a good reason not to break the contract of `equals`.

Comment: So it won't use equals-string override to cast User to String?

Comment: @Glebzex - No ... it won't.  You only get overriding if the parameter types (in the method signature) are identical.

Comment: I'd also add that you should override `hashCode` whenever you override `equals`.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I just checked the source code of HashMap. It appears (I checked in JDK 8) they compare the passed key to the keys of the existing entries, so `"asd".equals(a1)` returns false.

Comment: @Eran - Yup! I just got there too. Essentially - it is using `String.equals` instead of the hoped for `User.equals`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `public boolean equals(Object other)` and inside that method check for correct type of other object passed. Please note that the object passed *might be null* as well.

```
public class User {
  public boolean equals(Object other) {
    //Is the same
    if(other == this) {
      return true;
    }
    //Other is a user as well - Includes null-check (thanks, Kevin!)
    if(other instanceof User) {
      //equal if usernames are equal
      return login.equals(other.login);
    }
    //anything else - not equal / null, whatever
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: as a sidenode, checking `if(!(other instanceof User))` would do both, a null check and checking for the right class. Afterwards it´s clear that `other` represents a valid user object.